# AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: keras, python-3.6, keras-layer, triplet

I'm working on Triplets networks on Keras to find the image similarity. However, I'm getting an error when feeding triplets to the model. Request you to kindly help on this.

Basically I'm trying to feel the model with 3 inputs(anchor, positive, negative)

I'm working on Python3 and fitting the model with fit_model using Keras. This is my function to train the model:

```
def train(trainDB, testDB, n_iter, batch_size, evaluate_every, test_size, 
loss_every):
    print("Starting training process!")
    print("-------------------------------------")

    best = -1
    t_start = time.time()

    inputs=trainDB.getTripletTrainData(batch_size)
    targets=np.ones([batch_size])

    for i in range(0, n_iter):
        loss=tripletNet.fit(inputs, targets)

        #print("Loss: {0}".format(loss)) 

        if i % evaluate_every == 0:
            print("Time for {0} iterations: {1}".format(i, time.time()-t_start))
            val_acc = self.test_oneshot(testDB, test_size)
            if val_acc > best:
                print("Current best: {0}, previous best: {1}".format(val_acc, best))
                print("Saving weights to: {0} \n".format(weights_path))
                self.tripletNet.save_weights(weights_path)
                best=val_acc

        if i % loss_every == 0:
            print("iteration {}, training loss: {:.2f},".format(i,loss))
```

**Error message:**

```
Starting training process!
-------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-b5442e61de2d> in <module>()
----> 1 train(trainDatabase, testDatabase, n_iter, batch_size, evaluate_every, test_size, loss_every)

5 frames
<ipython-input-161-f417f0ebcfc7> in train(trainDB, testDB, n_iter, batch_size, evaluate_every, test_size, loss_every)
     10 
     11     for i in range(0, n_iter):
---> 12         loss=tripletNet.fit(inputs, targets)
     13 
     14         #print("Loss: {0}".format(loss))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
     90         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     91         data = [data]
---> 92     data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
     93 
     94     if len(data) != len(names):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     90         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     91         data = [data]
---> 92     data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
     93 
     94     if len(data) != len(names):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_single_array(x)
     25                 'Got tensor with shape: %s' % str(shape))
     26         return x
---> 27     elif x.ndim == 1:
     28         x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
     29     return x

**AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'ndim'**
```

If i use fit_generator.. Im getting the below error..

```
Starting training process!
-------------------------------------
Epoch 1/1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-b5442e61de2d> in <module>()
----> 1 train(trainDatabase, testDatabase, n_iter, batch_size, evaluate_every, test_size, loss_every)

3 frames
<ipython-input-193-8ad964a9916f> in train(trainDB, testDB, n_iter, batch_size, evaluate_every, test_size, loss_every)
     10 
     11     for i in range(0, n_iter):
---> 12         loss=tripletNet.fit_generator(inputs, targets)
     13 
     14         #print("Loss: {0}".format(loss))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1417             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1419 
   1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    178             steps_done = 0
    179             batch_index = 0
--> 180             while steps_done < steps_per_epoch:
    181                 generator_output = next(output_generator)
    182 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: It seems `inputs` is a generator. If that's the case, then you need to use `fit_generator` instead of `fit`.

Comment: thanks.. If i use fit_generator im getting the below error.

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'

Comment: Well, still unclear to me. Could you please instead show us the definition of `trainDB.getTripletTrainData`?

Comment: You pass 'inputs' and 'targets' to your fit_generator function. But, fit and fit_generator has different interfaces. fit_generator takes steps_per_epoch value which you pass your 'targets' variable onto. Since your steps_per_epoch is a np.array it can not be compared with steps_done(which is just 0). Therefore, the error message says that you cannot compare an array to a scalar value. Pass your parameters according to the interfaces of the functions you use.

Comment: thanks for your explanation.. it was really helpful...